OneSignal Push Notifications does'nt open app after dynamic icon change at android
I have an application with a dynamic icon-changing feature.
When clicking on push notifications, it opens the app
but after changing the dynamic icon the push notifications do not open app on Android.
I use flutter_dynamic_icon_plus for dynamic icon replacement.
Do you have any information about what may cause this problem?
Packages
onesignal_flutter: ^5.1.6
flutter_dynamic_icon_plus: ^1.2.1

Version
Flutter 3.19.6

Android Manifest

<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
  <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
  <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

  <service
          android:name="com.solusibejo.flutter_dynamic_icon_plus.FlutterDynamicIconPlusService"
          android:stopWithTask="false"/>


       
<meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2"/>

<activity-alias
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_birthday"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_birthday"
    android:name=".birthday"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:targetActivity="${applicationId}.MainActivity">

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
        android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
        />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity-alias>

<activity-alias
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_mourning"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_mourning"
    android:name=".mourning"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:targetActivity="${applicationId}.MainActivity">

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
        android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
        />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity-alias>

<activity-alias
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_year"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_year"
    android:name=".year"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:targetActivity="${applicationId}.MainActivity">

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
        android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
        />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity-alias>

<activity-alias
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_remembrance"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_remembrance"
    android:name=".remembrance"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:targetActivity="${applicationId}.MainActivity">

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
        android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
        />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity-alias>


I tried package upgrade but nothing change.

